# Слушатель для View, который срабатывает, когда его отпускают

Tags: android, android-view

Я знаю, что есть слушатель, который срабатывает, когда `View` (допустим кнопку) нажимают, но мне нужен слушатель, который срабатывает, когда ее отпускают! Есть ли такой слушатель, а если нет — как его создать\написать?

Comment: Переопределите метод `onTouch()` виджета и отлавливайте `MotionEvent` `UP` - палец отпустили от экрана.

Comment: @pavlofff, в ответ добавьте.

Comment: Вообще, `onClick()` ,и так срабатывает на отпускание. Уточните, что именно вам нужно изменить в поведении реакции а клик.

Comment: @pavlofff, во время нажатия на `LinearLayout` я буду делать его элементы серыми. Для этого, в начале, я буду делать `background` серым, при отпускании — возвращать белый.

Comment: а не проще ли selector к вьюхе прикрутить и все, а не менять bg в коде ручками?

Comment: @pavlofff, не проще. Такая `View` будет не одна, а тысячи дубликатов (я использую ее для адаптера). Я не могу менять цвет по `id`, так что... Или я Вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Да, по всей видимости Вы меня не правильно поняли, Вам понятие `selector` в adroid'e что  нить говорит?

Comment: @ermak0ff, нет... Я вообще `selector` использовал 2 раза и то, копировал с гугла (хотя и работало).

Comment: ну в общем если Вам надо что на протяжении нажатия элемент менял `bg` юзайте `selector`

Comment: @ermak0ff, а как менять его дочерние элементы (`background`), кроме как по `id`?

Comment: ну то есть у Вас имеется `ListView` каждый его `item` представляет собой `LinearLayout` с какими то вьюхами и Вы хотите что бы при нажатии на айтем менялся bg не только у самого контейнера но и у отдельных вьюх?

Comment: @ermak0ff, ну... Да! Только не с какими-то, а с 3-4 `TextView`. И цвет должен меняться не у контейнера, а именно у этих `View`. Эти `View` разделяет `1dp` черного цвета `LinearLayout`, так что его менять бесполезно, слишком мелко будет.

Comment: @bukashka101, может поможет android:duplicateParentState="true" у дочерних вьюх и также заюзать у них selector.